# Different partition sizes (lsblk and df)

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, df

I've been struggling to comprehend the discrepancy found in two outputs - `lsblk` and `df -h`. Searching among other similar questions didn't yield any good result.

***lsblk***:

```
sdb      8:16   0    10G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     5G  0 part /temp_disk
└─sdb2   8:18   0     5G  0 part /temp_disk_2
```

***df -h***:

```
/dev/sdb1       9.8G   24K  9.3G   1% /temp_disk
/dev/sdb2       4.9G   24K  4.6G   1% /temp_disk_2
```

How come the size of **/dev/sdb1** is bigger in the 2nd output? There, it equals to size of the whole disk (almost 10G).

**UPDATE**
After reboot, it was no longer possible to mount any of these partitions. Running `fsck` resulted in `Bad magic number in super-block` error which seems to confirm **mook765**'s assumption - some evil thing apparently happenned during partition resizing. To my memory, I might have forgotten to unmount a partition before resizing.

Comment: `lsblk` displays block device size, `df` displays filesystem size. Since in your case the filesystem is bigger than the block device which holds it, I'd say, something is wrong with that partition, maybe not properly resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to format the filesystem that was corrupted during erroneous resizing. In case of the two partitions I have, one need to:

1. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`
2. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2`

Once done, this solves all problems at once: there is no discrepancy in partition sizes, there are no bad super-blocks, and both partitions can be mounted without errors.